# PostgreSQL Extracting DOW and Changing timezone

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
extract(DOW FROM created_at) as DOW, --Sunday is 0, Saturday is 6--
count(*)
FROM 
zendesk_tickets z
WHERE 
city = 'Los Angeles'
AND 
created_at > '2013-07-08 07:00:00'
AND 
created_at < '2013-07-15 07:00:00'
AND tags NOT LIKE '%m_no_description%'
AND issue_type NOT IN ('Driver Account::Spam', 'Driver Trip Feedback::Wrong address    shown')
AND z.group like '%Driver Support'
AND z.group <> 'Driver Support'
GROUP BY DOW
ORDER BY DOW ASC
```

Which outputs:

```
DOW       COUNT
0          52
1          251
2          163
3          117
4          155
5          156
6          79
```

However, all times are timestamped in UTC in my database. Is there anyway to change this to make the timestamped data appear in PST (Pacific Standard Time) which is 7 hours behind?

Comment: is the `created_at` column a string or a timestamp?

Comment: created_at is a timestamp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select created_at at time zone 'PST'
from zendesk_tickets;
```

If you also want to *compare* the values in the where clause using that timezone you will need to use the `at time zone 'PST'` in each expression

Comment: The full time zone name might be a better choice; [the full time zone name](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-datetime.html) "implies a set of daylight savings transition-date rules," but abbreviations like 'PST' and 'PDT' do not.